# render() - how it loads controllers?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I give 401 Uanthourised acces header with

```
module.exports = function() {

    return function(req, res, next) {

        if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
            res.status(401);
            console.log('Unauthorized');

            res.render('login.html', { csrfToken: req.csrfToken() });

            return;
        }

        next();
    };
};
```

Now `login.html` is a view handled by completly different controller:

```
var passport = require('passport');
var config = require(__dirname + '/../lib/config');

module.exports = function (router) {

    router.get('/', function (req, res) {
        // Error flash messages
        var errorFlash = req.flash('error');
        if (errorFlash && errorFlash.length) {
            res.locals.error = errorFlash;
        }
        res.render('login.html', { csrfToken: req.csrfToken() });
    });

    router.post('/',
        passport.authenticate('local', {
            failureRedirect: '/login/',
            failureFlash: true
        }),
        function(req, res) {
            res.cookie(config.cookie.name, req.user.email, { signed: true, maxAge: 1234 });
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    );

};
```

My concern is how I can be sure what part of login controller fires up? `render('index.html')` somehow hooks up to `router.post()` in index controller and login form is handler as usual. How that can be?

Comment: Reason of minus or didin't happen

Comment: I think the minus' are because the question is confusing. `render('index.html')` will return a view (likely in `views/index.html`). The second code snippet you have included handles routing to the GET / and POST / routes. To answer your question, the view (which you haven't shown above) is what should 'hook up' with the `router.post()`.

If that doesn't clarify things, please rephrase your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controller will always go to "index" if you did not provide any method.
The reason that it is a "POST" is probably that you are trying to send a form to the index page. 
If you just request the index page. for example "(url)/login/index" or just "(url)/login" then it would be a "GET" request, but what are you trying to tell, I don't understand your question completely

Answer (score 1):

If you ever have any doubt which function is being called then a good approach is to (temporarily) add a console.log() within that function.  I will often do something like:

```
console.log('filename.js - functionname() called with args: [%s] [%s]', arg1, arg2);
```

And then watch the log for information about what fired off and what variables you're trying to watch.

It could be that you need to redirect rather than render in your 401-related code.

```
res.redirect('/login');
```

(Edited)

Comment: The redirect should be made to the route, not to the file